# How can I hide the Blown Shadows/Highlights Indicators in Camera Raw?

Tags: raw, photoshop, adobe-camera-raw, highlights, shadows

How do I stop Camera Raw showing blown blacks as blue and blown whites as red in Photoshop Camera Raw?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Camera RAW 7.0 you can just click on the little arrows on the top right or top left of the histogram display. The one on the left turns on/off the shadow indicator(blues), the one on the right turns on/off the highlight indicator(reds).

Alternatively you can use the keyboard "O" to toggle the highlight warning, and "U" to toggle the shadow warning.

[image]

More information about the indicators from Adobe: http://blogs.adobe.com/jkost/2013/03/per-channel-clipping-warnings-in-adobe-camera-raw-in-photoshop.html